# How to use data-saferedirecturl in a tag in PHP?

Tags: php, hyperlink, gmail

I want any other server request goes through my server just like link in *Gmail* and i checked it there `data-saferedirecturl=""`.

So how to use `data-saferedirecturl` in PHP automatcally in our website?

Exapmple:

```
<a href="xxxxx" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.mywebsite.com/url?hl=en&amp;q=xxxx">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 9):

All links in Gmail are interpreted in the browser.

The `data-saferedirecturl` tag is added automatically.

So the `href` shows the link that you will be clicking in the bottom of your browser but sends you to a google-originated URL like `https://www.google.com/url?hl=en-GB&site.com/324dd3`.

This way the third party don't have access to sensitive data.

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways to achieve this.

You can point all the redirects to the same page with the safe URL as a `GET` parameter (remember to use [urlencode](http://www.php.net/urlencode)):

```
<a href="/handler.php?safeurl=www.google.it%2Ftest"  target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Then in `handler.php` something like:

```
$desturl = isset($_GET["safeurl"]) ? $_GET["safeurl"] : false;
if($desturl != false){
    //do something
    header("location: ".$desturl);
}
```

If you want to use  `data-saferedirecturl` you have to use some JavaScript, and intercat somehow with your server (ex. ajax calls).

Example (using *jQuery*):

HTML:

```
<a href="xxxxx" class="test" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.mywebsite.com/url?hl=en&amp;q=xxxx">Link</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".test").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let url = $(this).data("saferedirecturl");
  // do ajax or check somehow the URL
  location.href = url;
})
```